# program life in terms of paged segmentation memory

Tags: linux, memory-management, operating-system, x86

I have a confusing notion about the process of segmentation & paging in x86 linux machines. Will be glad if some clarify all the steps involved from the start to the end.

x86 uses paged segmentation memory technique for memory management.

Can any one please explain what happens from the moment an executable .elf format file is loaded from hard disk in to main memory to the time it dies. when compiled the executable has different sections in it (text, data, stack, heap, bss). how will this be loaded ? how will they be set up under paged segmentation memory technique.

Wanted to know how the page tables get set up for the loaded program ? Wanted to know how GDT table gets set up. how the registers are loaded ? and why it is said that logical addresses (the ones that are processed by segmentation unit of MMU are 48 bits (16 bits of segment selector + 32 bit offset) when it is a bit 32 bit machine. how will other 16 bits be stored ? any thing accessed from ram must be 32 bits or 4 bytes how does the rest of 16 bits be accessed (to be loaded into segment registers) ?

Thanks in advance. the question can have a lot of things. but wanted to get clarification about the entire life cycle of an executable. Will be glad if some answers and pulls up a discussion on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as *paged segmentation*, not in the official documentation at least. There are two different mechanisms working together and more or less independently of each other:

1. Translation of a logical address of the form `16-bit segment selector value:16/32/64-bit segment offset value`, that is, a pair of 2 numbers into a `32/64-bit virtual address`.
2. Translation of the `virtual address` into a `32/64-bit physical address`.

Logical addresses is what your applications operate directly with. Then follows the above 2-step translation of them into what the RAM will understand, physical addresses.

In the first step the GDT (or it can be LDT, depends on the selector value) is indexed by the selector to find the relevant segment's base address and size. The virtual address will be the sum of the segment base address and the offset. The segment size and other things in segment descriptors are needed to provide protection.

In the second step the page tables are indexed by different parts of the virtual address and the last indexed table in the hierarchy gives the final, physical address that goes out on the address bus for the RAM to see. Just like with segment descriptors, page table entries contain not only addresses but also protection control bits.

That's about it on the mechanisms.

Now, in many x86 OSes the segment selectors that are used for applications are fixed, they are the same in all of them, they never change and they point to segment descriptors that have base addresses equal to 0 and sizes equal to the possible maximum (e.g. 4GB in non-64-bit modes). Such a GDT setup effectively means that the first step does no useful work and the offset part of the logical address translates into numerically equal virtual address.

This makes the segment selector values practically useless. They still have to be loaded into the CPU's segment registers (in non-64-bit modes into at least CS, SS, DS and ES), but beyond that point they can be forgotten about.

This all (except Linux-related details and the ELF format) is explained in or directly follows from Intel's and AMD's x86 CPU manuals. You'll find many more details there.

Comment: thanks alex, i have understood 90% of the explanation... wanted to ask... how would the segment selector is evaluated in case of non x86 systems ? also, why is the offset (second number in logical address) 16/32/64 ?

Comment: correct me.... when a program is brought from hard disk in to memory; the programs segments get assigned with logical addresses (16 bit selector + 32 offset) ? how is that 16 bit selector found out(is it done by compiler)... by the time the selector is loaded in to GDT shouldn't there be an entry in GDT table that corresponds to current program ? if so how is that GDT table entry populated ?

Comment: Not all CPUs have equivalents to x86 CPU segments. If they do, exactly how they work depends on the CPU. I can't talk of specific details of abstract non-x86 CPUs, at least one particular CPU needs to be chosen first. :) x86 CPUs have several different modes of operation with respect to operand sizes and their addressing in memory.

Comment: Contemporary x86 CPUs can work in 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit modes. Natural offset sizes in those modes are 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit. In the first two you can override the default with the opposite, that is, switch between 16 and 32, but the defaults are still 16 and 32. In 64-bit mode you can truncate offsets to 32 bits, but there's little to no benefit in that ability. The virtual addresses, though, on contemporary x86 CPUs are either 32-bit (in non-64-bit modes) or 64-bit (in 64-bit mode).

Comment: GDT is normally populated by the OS and the compiler has not a slightest idea of what it is and if it exists at all. The compiler usually pretends it operates directly with virtual addresses or that offsets and virtual addresses are the same thing. The OS decides what segment selector value will be there. Like I said earlier, in most cases those are some hard-coded selector values and they need not to be changed or saved or calculated or anything. The same selectors can be and are used in multiple apps. There's no interference because virt. adrs translate to different phys. adrs in difft apps.

Comment: There's also this `real mode`, which is a 16-bit mode, where GDT isn't used, but segments are and have to be used in order to address more than 64KB of memory. In this mode your `selector:offset` pair is translated directly to the physical address like this: `phys addr = selector * 16 + offset` (selector and offset are 16-bit). This makes it possible to address up to ~1MB of memory. Large MSDOS programs had much more code or data that could fit into a single segment (=64KB range of memory from selector*16 to selector*16+65535) and the compilers knew how to generate multi-segment code.

Comment: And not only they generated multi-segment code that loaded and reloaded segment registers when necessary, but also created and embedded into the executable files `segment relocation tables`, telling MSDOS how many segments there are and where in the program their selectors are needed so that MSDOS can adjust/patch those places as needed depending on where in memory the app gets loaded. But those segments are inconvenient to deal with. This is the very reason why in non-16-bit modes GDT is usually set up in such a way as if it didn't exist (virtual segment base address=0, segment size=maximum).

Comment: awesome alex... i got it completely now... in summary 
protected mode : no change of segment selectors. once loaded during boot by kernel and we are done.
real mode : there is a segment relocation table that takes care of this loading and unloading of segment registers. yup, that is messy.

Comment: thanks a lot alex for spending time on typing the big explanation. do u work with kernels ?

Comment: @kernel_os: I've played a little with them.

Comment: @kernel_os: in real mode, segment registers contain an actual address shifted right 4 bits which is added to the offset.

Comment: Thanks again alex. 
@ninjali... thanks for the clarification.. i understood that part

Answer (score 3):

Unix traditionally has implemented protection via paging. 286+ provides segmentation, and 386+ provides paging. Everyone uses paging, few make any real use of segmentation.

In x86, every memory operand has an implicit segment (so the address is really 16 bit selector + 32 bit offset), depending on the register used. So if you access `[ESP + 8]` the implied segment register is `SS`, if you access `[ESI]` the implied segment register is `DS`, if you access `[EDI+4]` the implied segment register is `ES`,... You can override this via segment prefix overrides.

Linux, and virtually every modern x86 OS, uses a flat memory model (or something similar). Under a flat memory model each segment provides access to the whole memory, with a base of 0 and a limit of 4Gb, so you don't have to worry about the complications segmentation brings about. Basically there are 4 segments: kernelspace code (RX), kernelspace data (RW), userspace code (RX), userspace data (RW).

An ELF file consists of some headers that pont to "program segments" and "sections". Section are used for linking. Program segments are used for loading. Program segments are mapped into memory via `mmap()`, this setups page-table entries with appropriate permissions.

Now, older x86 CPUs' paging mechanism only provided RW access control (read permission implies execute permission), while segmentation provided RWX access control. The end permission takes into account both segmentation and paging (e.g: RW (data segment) + R (read only page) = R (read only), while RX (code segment) + R (read only page) = RX (read and execute)).

So there are some patches that provide execution prevention via segmentation: e.g. OpenWall provided a non-executable stack by shrinking the code segment (the one with execute permission), and having special emulation in the page fault handler for anything that needed execution from a high memory address (e.g: GCC trampolines, self-modified code created on the stack to efficiently implement nested functions).

Comment: thanks ninjali, this is nearer to what i am looking for. so when mmap() ing, the program's segments get assigned some virtual address. (setting up page tables). how do we evaluate the segment selector ? in particular how does the implicit segment be evaluated ? is it hard coded in the table ?

Comment: @kernel_os: Note that x86 segments have nothing to do with ELF program segments.

Comment: my question how will the old real mode programs (no paging) will be loaded in to memory and how would a particular segment's base is populated in to segment registers. guess ALEX above has answered. Also, your comment says x86 segments have nothing to do with ELF segments... could you please comment more on this. thanks

Comment: @kernel_os: in DOS, .COM programs started with all the segment registers initialized to the same value. To use more segments, a program would call memory management functions and adjust segment registers appropriately. .EXE programs had headers to adjust the initial values for CS and SS (and to tell how much memory they needed, .COM programs were assumed to use all memory on startup), otherwise they are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps read the [Assembly HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/). When a Linux process starts to execute an ELF executable using the [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), it is essentially (sort of) [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)-ing some segments (and initializing registers, and a tiny part of the stack). Read also the [SVR4 x86 ABI supplement](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf) and its [x86-64 variant](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf). Don't forget that a Linux process only see memory mapping for its [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) and only cares about [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)

There are many good books on [Operating Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (=O.S.) [kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29), notably by [A.Tanenbaum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Tanenbaum) & by [M.Bach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997), and some on the [linux kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652)

NB: segment registers are nearly (almost) unused on Linux.